# How do I test whether two structural types are subtypes of each other?

Tags: python, python-typing, structural-typing

I have two Protocols in different modules.

```
class TooComplexProtocolInNeedOfRefactoring(Protocol):
    @property
    def useful(self) -> int:
        ...
    @property
    def irrelevant1(self) -> int:
        ...
    @property
    def irrelevant2(self) -> int:
        ...
    @property
    def irrelevant3(self) -> int:
        ...
```

and

```
class SpecificSubProtocol(Protocol):
    @property
    def useful(self) -> int:
        ...
```

I want to check that all classes that implement `TooComplexProtocolInNeedOfRefactoring` can be used for `SpecificSubProtocol`, so the former is a subtype of the latter.

All the tricks for checking structural subtypes I have found need instantiation or at least concrete classes, like

```
test_subtype: Type[SpecificSubProtocol] = TooComplexProtocolInNeedOfRefactoring
```

(“Can only assign concrete classes to a variable of type "type[SpecificSubProtocol]"”)

How can I test whether two protocols are structural subtypes of each other?

Comment: Do you want to check if `SpecificSubProtocol` actually *is* a subprotocol of `TooComplexProtocolInNeedOfRefactorying`? Because you can do that by simple inspection.

Comment: Yes, I do. But when I say TooComplexProtocolInNeedOfRefactorying, I mean it: It's huge and people are chipping away at refactoring it and it's in a different place from the SpecificSubProtocol, so it is not easy to do, and it can happen that someone edits one of the two without awareness for the other and then mypy will complain deep down the test code that brings them together – if we are lucky and nobody decided to cast() anything.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have to instantiate the protocol (at runtime or not). Just declare a type-checking-only variable whose type is that protocol:

<sub>(playground links: [Mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&flags=strict&gist=b80ea3d7d710dfe07705a486cbf304dd), [Pyright](https://pyright-play.net/?pythonVersion=3.13&strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoAK4MYAxmADYA0UAKgJoECiA%2BgMIASTbA0gJIA5AOIBYAFDjSFAIYBnWVADKCAKakkwJKUUBXAEZEwJchQAUh45QCUALnFQHUAAIJwqvHHuOAJiuBQdWT8dMyCKYCsoAFoAPkwUGDsxRxSoADoM8UkZeTowMDZIBAoVAA8LMko%2BFAEVFW8AeWAAJT9pUhIQVDRzYkqKWy8HFzcVDyGoX39A4NCVcMjY%2BMSJlIy0iZGwd3gJqcwQEHmVADdpBIBGUzCI6LjUFeTUh3XN122x3aeHfaRD47OCQATNd5rclg8ks8Xplvs53jtPHDfv8SoCYABmUELO7LKHQ14SMQaOiMVicbj8YT4hyoWQwc6kFQ2PIFIolcp9EzVWr1JqtYDtTrdKAAXnSGQcAGJYIhmZg0ChcCoJjAVPSWLJ9PBVCzlGoNFpdAYuZQxfF6YyVXCgA))</sub>

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
  # For Mypy, which is probably what you are using
  instance: TooComplexProtocolInNeedOfRefactoring
  # For Pyright
  instance: TooComplexProtocolInNeedOfRefactoring = ...  # type: ignore

  test_subtype: SpecificSubProtocol = instance  # this is fine
```

If the protocols didn't match (try removing one of the `useful()` methods) you would get a "Incompatible types in assignment" error or similar.